# Right after establishing a new connection to a DB need to execute a specific TSQL command. All is under EF5.0 (Model First)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012

Using Entity Framework 5.0, and MS SQL Server 2012. Implementing some cell level encryption functionality. This requires a specific set of actions to successfully encrypt/decrypt data:

1. Open encryption key (ex. executing OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TSQL command)
2. Execute the following SELECT DECRYPTBYKEY(key_guid, encryptedDate) AS Something FROM SomeTable

The question is: how, under Entity Framework 5.0 I can run OPEN KEY command right after the new connection to a DB is established? After the key is opened, it will stay open until this DB session is active.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can subscribe to the connection's `StateChange` event:

```cs
this.Database.Connection.StateChange += this.Connection_StateChange;
// "this" is the DbContext.

private void Connection_StateChange(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        // your commands here using sender as SqlConnection.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This works! Still, had to modify .tt file to make sure auto-generate feature will not overwrite my changes. May be there is a way to place this code to another partial file, not sure. This is good for now. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you could put it in a partial file beside the generated context class.